# android login volley error

Tags: android, authentication, android-volley

I am doing android login tutorial using volley from android hive. but when i tried it, it will go to volley error, i don't know why, i am just a beginner in android. Please help me. . I run my project in an emulator and connect it using usb debugging. My emulator is NOX.

I already finished the setup from the database.

After logging in, i want to intent my Dashboard class, but it doesn't intent , it goes with these erroe below

Here is the code where the error comes:

```
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(Login.this,
                        "VOLLEY ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
```

and the full code of that is this class:

```
package com.example.codeboxjohn.clinic.activity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.example.codeboxjohn.clinic.R;
import com.example.codeboxjohn.clinic.app.AppConfig;
import com.example.codeboxjohn.clinic.app.AppController;
import com.example.codeboxjohn.clinic.helper.SessionManager;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnLogin;
    private EditText inputUsername;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        //login
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String username = inputUsername.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                if(!username.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                    checkLogin(username, password);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void checkLogin(final String username, final String password) {
        //Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in..");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Create login session
                        session.setLogin(true);

                        // Inserting row in users table

                        // Launch main activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,
                                Dashboard.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "ERROR KO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(Login.this,
                        "VOLLEY ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if(!pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if(pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Comment: what are the error you getting ?

Comment: that sir.. volley error.

Comment: show the stacktrace.

Comment: change `"VOLLEY ERROR"`, to `error` and what you see ?

Comment: @ScottS i dont know how to show the stacktrace sir, i am just started learning android

Comment: @JohnJoe i'll try to change liek this sir: public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(Login.this,
                        error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }

Comment: @JohnJoe it says, com.android.volley.TimeoutError

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994514/volley-timeout-error

Comment: And also post [stacktrace](https://www.google.com/search?q=stacktrace&client=ubuntu&hs=Htv&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_q9T01uvSAhXBto8KHaDvC0UQ_AUICCgB&biw=1366&bih=673#imgrc=omcv9p4AaGx6_M:)

Comment: it seems like it is a problem with the URL, can you please post the url link?  The api might not exist, there might be a problem with the json response(i.e. a bracket missing in the response), test the api separately and see if it links to a valid json response.

Comment: i tried my URL/PHP in postman sir. it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the code you posted,

```
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {
```

I can see that you are not passing any request parameters (username and password) to the url.

As it is a `POST` request, request is required. Pass the request object you will get proper output.

Thanks