# volley.NoConnectionError

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm working on an Android app and currently stuck to link my database to my app for registration using volley but I get the problem:
this is response:

> com.android.volley.NoConnectionError:java.io.IOEXCEPTION: Cleartext HTTP traffic to 10.0.2.2 not permitted

Here is my MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        Button loginBtn;
        EditText password, username;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        password = findViewById(R.id.pssword);
        username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.check);

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                login();
            }
        });
    }

    void login() {
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
            "http://10.0.2.2:80/android/test.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is response: " + response, 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is response: " + error, 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("username", "hicham");
                params.put("password", "hello");

                return params;
            }
        };
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the usesCleartextTraffic="true" tag in your AndroidManifest.xml accordingly to fix this issue.

```
 <application
    
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

 </application>
```

This issue occurs because you are trying to access an http url instead of https and there are new restrictions regarding this lately. Hence, only after adding the tag I mentioned, your HTTP requests will work.

Happy coding! :)

Comment: i did that and i get TimeoutError, so i guess that did solve the first problem, and left me with another prblem

Comment: Send me the new error here. We'll resolve it!

Comment: I think the timeout error occurs because there's some issue with the url "http://10.0.2.2:80/android/test.php" as it can't be reached.

Comment: the error is "com.android:volley.TimeOutError"

Comment: everytime i resolve a problem i get another one, so i resolved the timeOutError problem from here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994514/volley-timeout-error) but i got a ClientError

Comment: basically the client error i changed the port by error and now it is working, thank you man for the help

Comment: That's great! :)